# dot2texi fails to convert automatically due to "Shell escape not enabled." not matter whether -shell-escape is specified to lualatex

Tags: luatex, shell-escape, dot2tex, dot2texi

The following document fails to compile properly/automatically because dot2texi fails to convert the dot specification and warns about it with

```
Package dot2texi Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(dot2texi)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..
```

not matter whether `-shell-escape` is passed to `lualatex` or not. No other options are given.

I'm experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with the installation provided by the `texlive-full` package.

An example document is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,autosize, scale=1.0, fdp]
  digraph G {
    A [texlbl="A"];
    B [texlbl="B"];
    A -> B [texlbl="transition 1"];
  }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

which results in the complete log

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) 
 system commands enabled.
(./kile_escape_shell_ignored.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /home/richter/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(
using read cache: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic /home/richter/.texlive201
7/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.174 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: /home/richte
r/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dot2texi/dot2texi.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
echo 'write18-test-2018751019'>"kile_escape_shell_ignored.w18"

Package dot2texi Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(dot2texi)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.geometric.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.misc.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.symbols.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.arrows.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.callouts.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.multipart.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryarrows.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-de-1901.
tex UTF-8 German hyphenation patterns (traditional orthography)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-de-1901.
tex
German Hyphenation Patterns (Traditional Orthography) `dehypht-x' 2017-03-31 (W
L))))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-de-1996.
tex UTF-8 German hyphenation patterns (reformed orthography)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-de-1996.
tex
German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2017-03-31
 (WL)))))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/gra
phs/tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/tex/tikzlibrarygrap
hdrawing.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/tex/pgflibrarygraph
drawing.code.tex)) (./kile_escape_shell_ignored.aux)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Opening dot2tex stream kile_escape_shell_ignored-dot2tex-fig1.dot
dot2tex --figonly --format=tikz    --autosize  --prog=fdp  --graphstyle="scale=
1.0,transform shape" -o kile_escape_shell_ignored-dot2tex-fig1.tex  kile_escape
_shell_ignored-dot2tex-fig1.dot

Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of kile_escape_shell_ignored-dot2tex-fig1.
dot failed..


Package dot2texi Warning: Please convert kile_escape_shell_ignored-dot2tex-fig1
.dot manually.

(./kile_escape_shell_ignored.aux))
 409 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 5 glue, 7 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 7 attribute_lis
t, 3 write, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:7,2:19,3:1,4:1,5:6,7:2,8:2,9:1,10:1,12:2

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on kile_escape_shell_ignored.log.
```

I'm aware that I can work around this issue by converting the graph manually. I want to solve the problem or understand why it can't be solved.

Comment: LuaTeX has changed the way it does --shell-escape. Add the line `\RequirePackage{shellesc}` before the \documentclass command. Also, when using XeTeX or LuaTeX don't use the inputenc command; they both assume UTF-8 input encoding.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thank you, that seems to be the answer (after testing), I'd be glad to reward it. That makes me think: Is having manpage giving the impression the LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, etc. are almost the same on Ubuntu (see `man lualatex`) really a good idea? That's something you'd expect to learn from a manpage, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LuaTeX has changed the way it does shell-escape and not all packages have caught up with that change. Place the line

```
\RequirePackage{shellesc}
```

before the documentclass command.